# How to export data to a TSV file using SheetJS on the client?

Tags: javascript, csv, sheetjs

Going through the [SheetJS docs](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx), I noticed exporting to a csv file is supported. And I have the working code, to convert an array of objects into a file and start the download:

```
let workSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(rows);
let workBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(workBook, workSheet);
XLSX.writeFile(workBook, 'export.csv');
```

But when it comes to tsv, there's only an [example to convert a sheet to text](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx#delimiter-separated-output):

```
> console.log(XLSX.utils.sheet_to_csv(ws, {FS:"\t"}));
S   h   e   e   t   J   S
1   2   3   4   5   6   7
2   3   4   5   6   7   8
```

The question is, how to get this kind of output, but in a file?

Answer (score 6):

After raising an [issue](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx/issues/1497) in the SheetJS github repository, I finally got the solution I was looking for:

```
XLSX.writeFile(workBook, 'export.tsv', {bookType:"csv", FS:"\t"});
```